# conflict between jquery 1.4.2 and jQuery 1.2.3

Tags: jquery

I am using the two above described libraries, one for a type writer effect on some `<ul>` and the other is used with a script to match floating `<div>`s height.

When I link the jQuery 1.2.3, the typewriter stops and shows all the `<ul>` contents?
what do you think I can do?

reference:

- Matching height: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery
- Text effect: http://web-development.tuljo.com/news-ticker-bbc-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys for trying to help.
I solved the problem by replacing the equal height plug-in to mootools:
http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-equal-heights

Answer (score 5):

You should only be using a single version of the jQuery library, not multiple ones.

If you need to choose, go with the newer one (in your case 1.4.2).

Comment: thanks guys but i can't get match height to work with the 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't try to mix two versions of the same library. that's just asking for things to break. Use the newer library and bring any requisite code up to date.

Comment: thanks guys but i can't get match height to work with the 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

For an up-to-date version of equalHeights, see the following:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.equalHeights = function(children) {
    return this.each(function() {

      var $this = $(this);
      var $children = $this.children();
      var highest = 0;

      $children.each(function(){
        var h = $(this).height();
        if (h > highest) {
          highest = h;
        }
      }).height(highest);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

// example usage: $('#equalize').equalHeights();
```

This is an updated and adapted version of [jQuery.equalheights.js](https://github.com/BBB/jquery-equalheights) plugin.